# Sharing data between controller and login/logout, ng-show/hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck at hiding and showing the login and logout elements at the navbar.  Simply Login page and navbar has different controllers. So when someone login in at login.html in order to hide elements at navbar which is owned by another controller I think i need share data between controllers. And another story is i need put cookie to same variable.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Mwhg3maL4XAIt3wLQhgn

```
.factory('Data', function(){

var data = { FirstName: '' }
return {
    getFirstName: function () {
        return data.FirstName;
    },
    setFirstName: function (myVar) {
        data.FirstName = myVar;
    }
};

})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $cookies, Data){

 $scope.$watch(function () { return Data.getFirstName(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) $scope.myVar = newValue;
});

//$scope.myVar = $cookies.get("Some");

})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, Auth, $state, Data){
$scope.myVar = '';

$scope.$watch('myVar', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) Data.setFirstName(newValue);
});

$scope.login = function() {

Auth.$authWithPassword({email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}).then(function(authData) {
  $scope.auth = true; //
      $scope.myVar =  true;
      $cookies.put('Some', true);
      $state.go('home');

})
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably resolve this using angular events

```
$scope.$emit('loggedIn', 'Some data perhaps?');

$scope.$on('loggedIn', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});
```